# Any way to get a reference for Actionbar items for Junit testing in android?

Tags: android, testing, junit, android-actionbar

How do I write junit test cases for actionbar items in android ? Any way of getting its reference for performing click events on it ?

Comment: Having the same problem while trying to test my Actionbar List-Navigation.

Comment: Actually is the same way with which you get references normally in Android, the only thing to keep in mind is that the tests are running in a different namespace, so you have to use the complete namespace of the original application.

Answer (score 3):

You can simulate clicking an ActionBar item like this:

```
public void testButton(){
    final View view = activity.findViewById(com.example.R.id.button1);
    activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            view.requestFocus();
            view.callOnClick();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: just an observation: `callOnClick()` was added in Api level 15, so it's not available in older versions. An alternative is `performClick()`.

Answer (score 1):

In this following example, i'm able to retrieve the navigation tab button of the action bar (native or ActionBarSherlock). Then i click on them with TouchUtils.clickView():

```
try {

// Trying to get the ActionBar view '@id/android:action_bar_container' dynamically
int resId =
a.getResources().getIdentifier("action_bar_container", "id", "android");
View actionBarContainer = a.findViewById(resId);

// The class 'com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContainer' must be in
// the classpath of this test project to be able to call
// the method 'getTabContainer' at runtime
Method getTabContainer =
com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContainer.class.getMethod("getTabContainer",
(Class<?>[]) null);

HorizontalScrollView tabContainer =
(HorizontalScrollView) getTabContainer.invoke(actionBarContainer, (Object[]) null);
return ((ViewGroup) tabContainer.getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(tabIndex);

} catch (Exception e) {

// Trying with SherlockActionBar
com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.ActionBarContainer actionBarContainer =
(com.actionbarsherlock...) a.findViewById(R.id.abs__action_bar_container);

HorizontalScrollView tabContainer =
(HorizontalScrollView) actionBarContainer.getTabContainer();
return ((ViewGroup) tabContainer.getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(tabIndex);

}
}
```

Comment: I got a similar idea while browsing the view hierarchy and was having problems because of the package name, android name seems to work great so thank you. Also note, if there are some views showing over you app you can also access them in this way, just find out the correct package name. It seems you can also access Notification bar elements in this way.

Answer (score 1):

use robotium.jar library

```
import com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.Solo;

private Solo solo;
this.solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation(),getActivity());
//R.id.menu_action_signup Menu Iten id.
this.solo.clickOnView(this.solo.getView(R.id.menu_action_signup));
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved by creating my own custom MenuItem class and calling  onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) for the Activity manually.
Any other proper way for doing this for Junit testing ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using an ActionBar provided by ActionBarSherlock and ran into this issue. The best way I've found to do this is:

1. In your test activity retain an instance of the Menu object passed in onCreateOptionsMenu and make this accessible to your test case.
2. In your test case you will need a reference to your Instrumentation and the Menu allowing you to select your MenuItem by id:

   ```
   private void clickOnMenuItem(int menuItemId, Instrumentation instruments, Menu menuInstance) {
   final Integer itemId = menuItemId;
   final Menu menu = menuInstance;
   instruments.runOnMainSync(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
           menu.performIdentifierAction(itemId, 0);
       }
   });
   ```

   }